# Is it possible to detect devTool openning or forbid it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, devtools

I'm trying to create an escape game in html/javascript ... Some important informations are in sessionStorage of the navigator. I want to forbid access to sessionStorage anyway for the player. I have a javascript code that forbid inspection with the devTools by CTRL+MAJ / right click and F12, but there is one way : the menu of navigator ...
Any idea to fobid or detect the access to the menu ?

Comment: AFAIK, no it's not possible (thankfully).

Comment: You shouldn't send anything to the client that you don't want the user to be able to see or modify. Anything that needs to be protected should be on the server, not the client. Hiding DevTools is not the appropriate solution.